Creating Azure dashboard using terraform
I am trying to create an Terraform code for Azure dashboards
I have written a terraform code to create the Azure dashboard, terraform code ran sucessfulenter image description herely but the dashboard was not created in the UI
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resource"
  location = "West US 2"

}


resource "azurerm_dashboard" "example" {
  name                = "example-dashboard"
  resource_group_name = "example-resource" # Replace with your resource group name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location  # Replace with your desired location

dashboard_properties = jsonencode({
    "lenses": {
      "0": {
        "order": 1,
        "parts": {
          "0": {
            "position": {
              "x": 0,
              "y": 0,
              "rowSpan": 1,
              "colSpan": 1
          },
          "settings" : {
            "type" : "azuresharedmetric",
            "resourceId" : "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/example-resource/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/dash",
            "metrics" : [
              {
                "name" : "Percentage CPU",
                "aggregation" : "Average"
              }
            ],
            "timeAggregation" : "Average"
          }
        }
        }
    }
  }
}
)

  tags = {
    environment = "example"
  }
}

Output expected was dashboard to be created but it failed .enter image description here

Which terraform provider version you are using. @Nevin

@Jahnavi terraform _version 1.8.4 hasicorp/azurerm 2.66.0

You can check the below answer. @Nevin

Firstly, when you are deploying the terraform code, make sure that the version has been upgraded to the latest azurerm4.0.1 to avoid conflicts.
In previous provider releases, azurerm_dashboard is available. But now, you need to use the azurerm_portal_dashboard once you upgraded the azurerm version.
Below is the modified code of yours which worked for me as expected.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "4.0.1"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
subscription_id="xxxx"
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "Jahnavi"
}

resource "azurerm_portal_dashboard" "example" {
  name                = "example-dashboard"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location

  dashboard_properties = jsonencode({
    "lenses": {
      "0": {
        "order": 1,
        "parts": {
          "0": {
            "position": {
              "x": 0,
              "y": 0,
              "rowSpan": 2,
              "colSpan": 3
            },
            "metadata": {
              "type": "Extension/HubsExtension/PartType/SharedMetricPart",
              "inputs": [
                {
                  "name": "resourceType",
                  "value": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
                },
                {
                  "name": "resourceId",
                  "value": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/Jahnavi/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/newdashvm"
                },
                {
                  "name": "metricNamespace",
                  "value": "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
                },
                {
                  "name": "metricName",
                  "value": "Percentage CPU"
                },
                {
                  "name": "aggregation",
                  "value": "Average"
                },
                {
                  "name": "timeAggregation",
                  "value": "Average"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
  tags = {
    environment = "example"
  }
}

If needed, you can include the metadata block in the above code.
Output:


And also, I have tried the sample template code to check if it is working in different types of scenarios and was able to deploy it successfully as shown in the below output snap.

Refer here for dashboard modules alternatively.

i was able to deploy thanks for you help however why does it not show any metrics

Under virtual machine, you are checking? @Nevin
